# i am finding a way to increase rollup summary fields in scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, package.xml

like wise to make scratch org we have

`"features": ["PersonAccounts"],`

in dx is there any way to increase the roll up summary fields for scratch org or workaround   any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't increase feature limits (Apex Characters, Lookup Fields Per Object, Workflow Rule Limits, etc) at this time. You may want to ask your Account Executive about the Org Shape feature (it's a pilot), as this may help you, or you'll have to wait until a feature like this becomes available.